# Long running task in DLL report progress

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dll

I've written a little C# DLL project that reads data from Excel files and writes it to a Sqlite database. How can i report the progress to the main program that uses the DLL? (It could be a Windows form executable)

Thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=net-6.0

Comment: Thanks! I ws able to do It with Progress and async await